# setting up opengl and glut on windows 7

Tags: opengl, glut, netbeans-6.9

i have cygwin and netbeans installed on my computer working compatibly. I want to set up opengl and glur and bind those to my c/c++ projects in Netbeans? However, I couldn't find a way how to set up opengl and glut on w7. Any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [GLUT page](http://www.cs.csustan.edu/~rsc/SDSU/GLUTinstall.html) on www.opengl.org includes a link to [these instructions](http://www.cs.csustan.edu/~rsc/SDSU/GLUTinstall.html). Have you tried this method?

Note that they seem to be specific to Microsoft Visual C++. Make sure you replace the paths so that they match your NetBeans installation.

Answer (score -1):

Having just gone through this pain to get some example programs up and running that rely on GLUT this is what worked for me.

Sign to be a developer for NIVIDA (https://developer.nvidia.com/join) and use their now legacy CG toolkit (https://developer.nvidia.com/cg-toolkit-download). You might want to see if you can download that without being a developer.

This includes both a 32 bit and a 64 bit pre-compiled GLUT library and header. See the following URL: http://http.developer.nvidia.com/Cg/glut.html

he Cg Toolkit installer for Windows provides a pre-compiled 32-bit (and 64-bit if selected) versions of GLUT. GLUT is provided both as a Dynamic Link Library (DLL) and a static library.

The GLUT DLL is called glut32.dll and requires linking against glut32.lib. These 32-bit versions are typically installed at:

c:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\Cg\bin\glut32.dll
c:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\Cg\lib\glut32.lib

The 64-bit (x64) versions are installed at:

c:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\Cg\bin.x64\glut32.dll
c:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\Cg\lib.x64\glut32.lib

Which is wierd I know, but glut is super old and lots of things require the name to be specifically "glut32" even for 64 compiliing.

Hope this helps!